# Custom API plugin to execute 3rd party API to retrieve data

Tags: plugins, customization, security, rest-api, api

I am new to WordPress here.

I have this request where I need to create a custom REST API plugin where when user triggers the following URL link:

`www.example.com/wp-json/v1/getCoupon/123456?CouponID=MacD`

The plugin will perform the following:

a. Execute CURL POST (using the username and password stored within the plugin) to retrieve the token

b. Execute CURL GET using the token retrieved, order number and coupon ID (specified in the URL) to retrieve the coupon information.

Is there any security concern the credential stored within the plugin?

Is this setup approach feasible?

Seeking experts here for advise

Answer (score 1):

If you need to pass username and password for Basic Auth you need to send that in headers e.g.

```
$headers = array('Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( YOUR_USERNAME . ':' . YOUR_PASSWORD );

$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method'      => 'POST',
    'timeout'     => 45,
    'headers'     => $headers
    )
);
```

If you need to pass username and password as value you can send it in body e.g.

```
$response = wp_remote_post( $url, array(
    'method'      => 'POST', // Use 'GET' for GET request
    'timeout'     => 45,
    'headers'     => array(),
    'body'        => array(
        'username' => 'test',
        'password' => 'xxxx'
    ),
    )
);

//Get the response
if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
    $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
    echo "Something went wrong: $error_message";
} else {
    echo 'Response:<pre>';
    print_r( $response ); // You will get the token in $response, the $response usually in JSON or XML.
    echo '</pre>';
}
```

Once you have the token you can send that in URL again to `wp_remote_post` function

For your other question you must encrypt any sensitive information and decrypt it when you need it.